# GameObject activates too soon

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

**EDIT**

So it's in here, of this I have no doubt, but why? NextOne.active = true; is firing off regardless of whether the action button is being pressed.

```js
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_3 == true)
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
    Playerhealthscript.panic +=1;
    print("1 works");
    Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
    Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
    Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
    Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;
    NextOne.active = true;
}  
else if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_4 == true)
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
    Playerhealthscript.insanity +=1;
    print("2 works");
    Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
    Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
    Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
    Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;
    NextOne.active = true;
}
```

The way that I'm reading this, if action button is pressed AND Opt 3 OR Opt 4 are active then the following should happen:

An audio clip is played Insanity OR Panic are increased by 1 in the Playerhealth script A message is printed in the console Options 3 & 4 are deactivated NextOne is activated.

**So what am I not seeing here? Why is NextOne activating with or without action being pressed? Is my syntax wrong?**

**END EDIT**

Let me tell you what my script is *supposed* to do:

Some text appears. A question with an A/B choice appears. You choose A or B. This activates a GameObject which has a similar script on it. That script immediately disables the script you were just one. You answer another A/B question. (this time from the new script, since the old one has been deactivated) Once you answer the second question (only one on the new script) a third GameOBject activates, with another, similar script again, with the same results. It's a chain. So basically it goes
GameObject 1 is active at start of scene. (Script1) A/B choice is made GameObject 1 is deactivated GameObject 2 is activated(Script2) New A/B choice is made GameObject3 is activated(Script3) and so on.
It should be a simple on / off switch script, but here 's what's happening:
When the player makes the first decision instead of going from GameObject 1 to GameObject 2 the script is bypassing 2 and going straight to 3. Here is the script from 1 to 2:

```js
//boolean variables
var Speaking : boolean = false;
var Entered : boolean = false;
var Speaking2 : boolean = false;
var Entered2 : boolean = false;
var Speaking3 : boolean = false;
var Entered3 : boolean = false;
var Speaking4 : boolean = false;
var Entered4 : boolean = false;

var Op_1 : boolean = false;
var Op_2 : boolean = false; 
var Op_3 : boolean = false;
var Op_4 : boolean = false; 


//speaking variables
var speakername : String;
var theselines : String;
var theselines2 : String;
var theselines3 : String;
var theselines4 : String;
var theselines5 : String;
var these2lines : String;
var these2lines2 : String;
var these2lines3 : String;
var these2lines4 : String;
var these2lines5 : String;
var these3lines : String;
var these3lines2 : String;
var these3lines3 : String;
var these3lines4 : String;
var these3lines5 : String;
var these4lines : String;
var these4lines2 : String;
var these4lines3 : String;


//other variables
var Background : GameObject;
var Option_1_Unselected : GameObject;
var Option_2_Unselected : GameObject;
var Option_1_SELECTED : GameObject;
var Option_2_SELECTED : GameObject;
var NextOne : GameObject;

var MouseLookScript : MouseLook;
public var guiSkin : GUISkin;
var OptionsSound : AudioClip;
var MoveSound : AudioClip;
var Playerhealthscript : Playerhealth;

function Start () {
    Entered = true;
}

function Continued(){
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.25);
    Entered = false;
    Speaking = false;
    Entered2 = true;
}

function Continued2(){
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.25);
    Entered2 = false;
    Speaking2 = false;
    Entered3 = true;
}

function Continued3(){
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.25);
    Entered3 = false;
    Speaking3 = false;
    Entered4 = true;
}



function OnGUI(){
    if(Entered){
        Background.active = true;
        MouseLookScript.enabled = false;
        Speaking = true;
        GUI.skin = guiSkin;
        GUI.Label(Rect(410,295,400,175), speakername);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,345,400,175), theselines);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,380,400,175), theselines2);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,415,400,175), theselines3);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,455,400,175), theselines4);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,495,400,175), theselines5);
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action")){
            Continued();
        }
    }

    if(Entered2){
        Speaking2 = true;
        GUI.skin = guiSkin;
        GUI.Label(Rect(410,295,400,175), speakername);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,345,400,175), these2lines);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,380,400,175), these2lines2);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,415,400,175), these2lines3);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,455,400,175), these2lines4);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,495,400,175), these2lines5);
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action")){
            Continued2();
        }
    }

    if(Entered3){
        Speaking3 = true;
        GUI.skin = guiSkin;
        GUI.Label(Rect(410,295,400,175), speakername);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,345,400,175), these3lines);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,380,400,175), these3lines2);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,415,400,175), these3lines3);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,455,400,175), these3lines4);
        GUI.Label(Rect(500,495,400,175), these3lines5);
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action")){
            Continued3();
        }
    }

    //Question_1
    if(Entered4)
    {
        Speaking4 = true;
        GUI.skin = guiSkin;
        GUI.Label(Rect(410,295,400,175), speakername);
        GUI.Label(Rect(415,345,400,175), these4lines);
        GUI.Label(Rect(415,380,400,175), these4lines2);
        GUI.Label(Rect(415,415,400,175), these4lines3);
        Option_1_SELECTED.active = true;
        Option_2_Unselected.active = true;
        Option_1_Unselected.active = false;
        Option_2_SELECTED.active = false;
        Op_1 = true;
        Op_2 = false;

        if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < -.5)
        {
            Option_1_SELECTED.active = false;
            Option_2_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_1_Unselected.active = true;
            Option_2_SELECTED.active = true;
            Op_1 = false;
            Op_2 = true;
            print("this works");
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_1 == true)
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
            Playerhealthscript.panic +=1;
            print("1 works");
            Option_1_SELECTED.active = false;
            Option_2_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_1_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_2_SELECTED.active = false;
            NextOne.active = true;
        }
        else if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_2 == true)
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
            Playerhealthscript.insanity +=1;
            print("2 works");
            Option_1_SELECTED.active = false;
            Option_2_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_1_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_2_SELECTED.active = false;
            NextOne.active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the trick I think, so I believe that the problem resides somewhere in the script for 2 to 3. Below is the script for 2 to 3.

```js
#pragma strict

//boolean variables

var Speaking5 : boolean = false;
var Entered5 : boolean = false;

var Op_3 : boolean = false;
var Op_4 : boolean = false; 


//speaking variables
var speakername : String;

var these5lines : String;
var these5lines2 : String;
var these5lines3 : String;


//other variables
var Background : GameObject;
var Option_3_Unselected : GameObject;
var Option_4_Unselected : GameObject;
var Option_3_SELECTED : GameObject;
var Option_4_SELECTED : GameObject;
var OldOne : GameObject;
var NextOne : GameObject;


var MouseLookScript : MouseLook;
public var guiSkin : GUISkin;
var OptionsSound : AudioClip;
var MoveSound : AudioClip;
var Playerhealthscript : Playerhealth;




function Start () {
    OldOne.active = false;
    NextOne.active = false;
    Entered5 = true;
}

function OnGUI(){

    if(Entered5)
    {
        Speaking5 = true;
        GUI.skin = guiSkin;
        GUI.Label(Rect(410,295,400,175), speakername);
        GUI.Label(Rect(415,345,400,175), these5lines);
        GUI.Label(Rect(415,380,400,175), these5lines2);
        GUI.Label(Rect(415,415,400,175), these5lines3);
        Option_3_SELECTED.active = true;
        Option_4_Unselected.active = true;
        Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
        Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;
        Op_3 = true;
        Op_4 = false;

        if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < -.5)
        {
            Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
            Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_3_Unselected.active = true;
            Option_4_SELECTED.active = true;
            Op_3 = false;
            Op_4 = true;
            print("this works");
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_3 == true)
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
            Playerhealthscript.panic +=1;
            print("1 works");
            Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
            Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;
            NextOne.active = true;
        }
        else if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_4 == true)
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
            Playerhealthscript.insanity +=1;
            print("2 works");
            Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
            Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
            Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;
            NextOne.active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm noticing that if I comment out NextOne.active = true; in script 2 the question gets asked properly, but then obviously script 3 doesn't fire off. So I'm wondering if it's placement. I've moved it around, even put it in its own function with no success.

Comment: Stop using OnGui and start using [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui)

Comment: ok, well, before I go reinventing the wheel any suggestions on how to fix this script?

Comment: I have no ideas, sorry. The setup you have is convoluted and should be refactored to a more elegant dialog system.

Comment: Your code formatting is quite useless and the method seems quite overcomplicating to me ... but my very first guess: The moment the Player clicks, you activate script 2 and probably it jumps directly into `OnGui` while `Input.GetButtonDown` is still `true` -> it goes straight on to script 3

Comment: Also note that instead of setting `NextOne = false` in `Start()` you should probably do it in `OnEnabled()` and use `NextOne.SetActive(false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! My son pointed out that all I needed to do was add an integer every time a question was answered, then make that integer a condition to go on to the next question.

```js
#pragma strict

//boolean variables

var Speaking5 : boolean = false;
var Entered5 : boolean = false;

var Op_3 : boolean = false;
var Op_4 : boolean = false; 
var Question : int = 0;


//speaking variables
var speakername : String;
var addhealth : String;
var addhealth2 : String
var these5lines : String;
var these5lines2 : String;
var these5lines3 : String;
 

//other variables
var Background : GameObject;
var Option_3_Unselected : GameObject;
var Option_4_Unselected : GameObject;
var Option_3_SELECTED : GameObject;
var Option_4_SELECTED : GameObject;
var OldOne : GameObject;
var NextOne : GameObject;



var MouseLookScript : MouseLook;
public var guiSkin : GUISkin;
var OptionsSound : AudioClip;
var MoveSound : AudioClip;
var Playerhealthscript : Playerhealth;


function Update(){
if(Question >= 1)
 {
 NextOne.active = true;
}

}

function Start () {
OldOne.active = false;
//NextOne.active = false;
Entered5 = true;
}
 
function OnGUI(){

if(Entered5)
{
Speaking5 = true;
GUI.skin = guiSkin;
GUI.Label(Rect(410,295,400,175), speakername);
GUI.Label(Rect(415,345,400,175), these5lines);
GUI.Label(Rect(415,380,400,175), these5lines2);
GUI.Label(Rect(415,415,400,175), these5lines3);
Option_3_SELECTED.active = true;
Option_4_Unselected.active = true;
Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;
Op_3 = true;
Op_4 = false;

if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < -.5)
  {
Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
Option_3_Unselected.active = true;
Option_4_SELECTED.active = true;
Op_3 = false;
Op_4 = true;
  print("this works");

  }
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_3 == true)
{
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
Playerhealthscript.panic +=1;
print("1 works");
Question += 1;
Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;

}

else if(Input.GetButtonDown("Action") && Op_4 == true)
{
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(OptionsSound, transform.position); 
Playerhealthscript.insanity +=1;
print("2 works");
Question += 1;
Option_3_SELECTED.active = false;
Option_4_Unselected.active = false;
Option_3_Unselected.active = false;
Option_4_SELECTED.active = false;
}
}
}
```